# Javascript - Get element behind caret in child elements of [contenteditable]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, contenteditable

I am building a simplistic and easy-to-use text editor in Javascript, basically a WYSIWYG editor. I will be using the `contenteditable` attribute to the main wrapper (`.wrapper`). When you press enter inside the `.wrapper`, a new `<p>` element with a unique `id` gets appended to the wrapper.

I need a way to fetch which child element of the `.wrapper` that is currently selected (i.e., being focused or having the caret/text marker inside of it).

I've searched for days without any results, and I've tried using `document.elementFromPoint()` but without any proper results.

When using `$(":focus")`, I get the entire `.wrapper` and not the specific child element.

**Edit:**

Example HTML structure:

```
<div class="container t-wrapper" contenteditable>
</div>
```

Example Javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $currentElement = $("[contenteditable]");

    $(".t-wrapper").each(function() {
        var id = generateIdentifier(6); // Ignore this

        /* This creates the initial <p> child element, where you start typing. */
        $(this).html('<p class="t-empty t-first" id="' + id + '"></p>');

        $(this).on("mouseup", function() {
            /* $currentElement = whatever element the caret is inside. */
        });

        $(this).on("keyup", function() {
            /* $currentElement = whatever element the caret is inside. */
        });
    ));
});
```

**Edit 2:**

I managed to get it fairly working with the `mouseup` event, since you're actually clicking on something. But I need this to work when moving the caret using the **keyboard**. Alternatively, I need some way to get the position of the caret in pixels, and then use `document.elementFromPoint()` to get the specific element.

Comment: Have you tried using contenteditable on only the selected node? For example you could set the new `p` to `contenteditable="true"` while disabling it for all other elements. When navigating the node tree (click or arrow key) you could shift the `contenteditable` property to the next element. This seems to at least make the child nodes searchable with `:focus`.

Comment: a piece of code, please?

Comment: @freestock.tk Added some basic sample code.

Comment: Thank you very much. If I found something new I'll let you know.

Comment: @E.Sundin I tried your suggestion, but changing the `contenteditable` all over the place just messed things up

Answer (score 2):

`:focus` doesn't select your elements because they are not focusable.

You can make them focusable by adding `tabindex="-1"` in HTML, or `tabIndex = -1` in JS.

```js
var generateIdentifier = Math.random;
var currentElement = document.querySelector("[contenteditable]");
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll(".t-wrapper"), function(el) {
  var first = document.createElement('p');
  first.className = "t-empty t-first";
  first.id = generateIdentifier(6);
  first.textContent = 'Press enter to create new paragraphs';
  first.tabIndex = -1;
  el.appendChild(first);
});
```

```css
.container > :focus {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container t-wrapper" contenteditable></div>
```

It seems that if you add it to the first paragraph, new paragraphs obtain it automatically. But if you want to be sure, I guess you could use a mutation observer or a keyup event listener to detect paragraphs without `tabindex`, and add it:

```js
el.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
  var newChild = el.querySelector('p:not([tabindex])');
  if(newChild) newChild.tabIndex = -1;
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I'll be sure to test this. You first mentioned `tabindex="1"`, but in the code you specified the index as `-1`. Why is that? Typo?

Comment: @DanielPox I meant `-1`. When you press the tab key, focus goes to the next focusable element according to the `tabindex`. `tabindex = -1` makes an element focusable but not iterable by the tab key. Use a positive number if you want them to be iterable.

Comment: Damn, Chrome does not consider the paragraphs to be focused when you are writing in them, even if they are focusable.

Answer (score -1):

`document.activeElement` will return the currently focused element.

Comment: This is the same as writing `$(":focus")`, this marks the entire `.wrapper` since that's the element with the `contenteditable` attribute I guess.